# How to use Prometheus in Kubernetes with AWS EBS?

Tags: kubernetes, storage, prometheus, amazon-ebs, kubernetes-helm

I created an EBS volume with 30 GiB size. Made two manifest files:

- pv-ebs.yml
- pvc-ebs.yml

In pv-ebs.yml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: ebs
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 30Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
  awsElasticBlockStore:
    fsType: ext4
    # The EBS volume ID
    volumeID: vol-111222333aaabbbccc
```

in pvc-ebs.yml

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: prometheus-prometheus-alertmanager
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      release: "stable"

---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: prometheus-prometheus-server
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      release: "stable"
```

Use `helm` installed it: `helm install --name prometheus stable/prometheus`.

But on the k8s dashboard, got message:

```
prometheus-prometheus-alertmanager-3740839786-np7kb
No nodes are available that match all of the following predicates:: NoVolumeZoneConflict (2).

prometheus-prometheus-server-3176041168-m3w2g
PersistentVolumeClaim is not bound: "prometheus-prometheus-server" (repeated 2 times)
```

Is there anything wrong about my method?

### Pods

[image]

### Persistent Volumes

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When EBS is created, it is provisioned in a particular AZ and it can not be cross-zone mounted. If you do not have nodes available in the same zone for scheduling the pod, it will not start.

Another thing is that with a properly configured kube cluster, you should not need to create PV on your own at all, just create PVC and let [dynamic provisioning](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#dynamic) do it's thing.

Comment: I can install `Prometheus` from Rancher catalog. Then install `Kubernetes`.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed your cluster with KOPs the PVs will be created for you automatically. Just wait a few min and refresh your screen. The errors will go away.

If you have setup your cluster in another way you want to create your volumes in AWS ec2 create-volume and then create PVs and then when helm runs it will claim those PVs.